# Can I add inequalities the same way I can add equations?

Tags: inequality

Specifically, if $$ A \leq B \leq C $$ and $$ D \leq E \leq F $$, then is $$ A + D \leq B + E \leq C + F $$ true?

This is just something I need to know for a problem set. I can't really find a definitive answer on google either.

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

$ \color{red}{A  \leq B }$ and $\color{blue}{ D \leq E}$ so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{red}{A}+D  \color{red}{ \leq B}+ \color{blue}{D \leq }  B +\color{blue}{E}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, it's true.

For the proof use the following "definition":
$$a>b\Leftrightarrow a-b>0.$$

For example:

Let $A\leq B$ and $D\leq E$. Prove that:
$$A+D\leq B+E.$$
Indeed, since $A\leq B$ and $D\leq E$, we have $B-A\geq0$ and $E-D\geq0.$

Thus, $$B+E-(A+D)=(B-A)+(E-D)\geq0,$$
which gives $$B+E\geq A+D$$ or
$$A+D\leq B+E.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you just focus on $A \le B$ and $D \le E$:

$$A + D \le \text{ (since } A \le B \text{)}$$

$$B + D \le \text{ (since } D \le E \text{)}$$

$$B + E$$